# Why am i getting this: PLSQL String length constraint Error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

i have being working on this code for a while now and have tried everything i can think of.

This is the code block:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_LOCATION_TO_DB (ploccode VARCHAR2, pminqty 
NUMBER, pmaxqty NUMBER)AS
    Err_Locode_Length EXCEPTION;
    Err_Minqty_Range EXCEPTION;
    Err_Maxqty_Range EXCEPTION;
    Err_Maxqty_Greater_Minqty EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
    IF LENGTH(ploccode) != 5 THEN
        RAISE Err_Locode_Length;
    ELSE IF pminqty > 10 OR pminqty < 0 THEN
        RAISE Err_Minqty_Range;
    ELSE IF pmaxqty > 10 OR pmaxqty < 0 THEN
        RAISE Err_Maxqty_Range;
    ELSE IF pminqty > pmaxqty THEN
        RAISE Err_Maxqty_Greater_Minqty;
    END IF;
    END IF;
    END IF;
    END IF;
INSERT INTO LOCATION
VALUES (ploccode, pminqty, pmaxqty);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20081,'Duplicate Location ID');
    WHEN Err_Locode_Length THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20082,'Location Code Lenght invalid');
    WHEN Err_Minqty_Range THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20083,'Minium Qty is out of range');
    WHEN Err_Maxqty_Range THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20084,'Maximum Qty is out of range');
    WHEN Err_Maxqty_Greater_Minqty THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20086,'Minium Qty is Lager than Maximum Qty');
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'Use Value of SQLERRM');
END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_LOCATION_VIASQLDEV AS
    Dis_Msg VARCHAR2;
    ploccode VARCHAR2;
    pminqty NUMBER;
    pmaxqty NUMBER;
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('--------------------------------------------------');
    dbms_output.put_line('Adding location  LocCode: ' || ploccode || ' MinQty: ' || pminqty || 'MaxQty' || pmaxqty);
    ADD_LOCATION_TO_DB(ploccode, pminqty, pmaxqty);
    dbms_output.put_line(Dis_Msg);
END;
/
```

When i run this set of procedures i get an error in the compiler stating:

> Error(1,13): PLS-00215: String length constraints must be in range (1 .. 32767)
>
> Error(2,14): PLS-00215: String length constraints must be in range (1 .. 32767)

I have tried adding constraints to the code that calls the main Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_LOCATION_VIASQLDEV AS
    Dis_Msg VARCHAR2(40);
    ploccode VARCHAR2(5);
    pminqty NUMBER(2);
    pmaxqty NUMBER(2);
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('--------------------------------------------------');
    dbms_output.put_line('Adding location  LocCode: ' || ploccode || ' MinQty: ' || pminqty || 'MaxQty' || pmaxqty);
    ADD_LOCATION_TO_DB(ploccode, pminqty, pmaxqty);
    dbms_output.put_line(Dis_Msg);
END;
/
```

Adding these constrains does remove the errors with the compiler however i still revive errors when executing this testing code:

```
Error starting at line : 48 in command -
begin
dbms_output.put_line('Student ID: 1234567');
dbms_output.put_line('==========PART 3 TEST LOCATIONS==========================');
ADD_LOCATION_VIASQLDEV ('AF201',1,2);
ADD_LOCATION_VIASQLDEV('AF202',-3,4);
ADD_LOCATION_VIASQLDEV ('AF203',5,1);
ADD_LOCATION_VIASQLDEV ('AF204',6,7000);
ADD_LOCATION_VIASQLDEV ('AF20111',8,9);
end;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 4, column 1:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ADD_LOCATION_VIASQLDEV'
ORA-06550: line 4, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 5, column 1:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ADD_LOCATION_VIASQLDEV'
ORA-06550: line 5, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 6, column 1:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ADD_LOCATION_VIASQLDEV'
ORA-06550: line 6, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 7, column 1:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ADD_LOCATION_VIASQLDEV'
ORA-06550: line 7, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 8, column 1:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ADD_LOCATION_VIASQLDEV'
ORA-06550: line 8, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Can some one please tell me what i'm doing wrong.

Apologies if this is to much information or my formating is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confused between the declaration section and arguments sections of the procedure.

- Your first error is due to the fact that you placed your supposedly arguments in the declaration section. then when you tried to add length to it, it compiled, but you left the procedure without arguments. then you run it with four arguments which caused the error since the procedure is created accepting no arguments.

  ```
  create or replace procedure_name(
                                   parameter1 datatype, --arguments section
                                   parameter2 datatype
                                   ) AS
  /*declaration section*/
  variable1 datatype(length);
  variable2 datatype(length);
  BEGIN

  /*your code here*/

  END;
  ```

try this revise script

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_LOCATION_VIASQLDEV (Dis_Msg VARCHAR2,
                                                    ploccode VARCHAR2,
                                                    pminqty NUMBER,
                                                    pmaxqty NUMBER ) AS 
BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line('--------------------------------------------------');
dbms_output.put_line('Adding location  LocCode: ' || ploccode || ' MinQty: ' || pminqty || 'MaxQty' || pmaxqty);
ADD_LOCATION_TO_DB(ploccode, pminqty, pmaxqty);
dbms_output.put_line(Dis_Msg);
END;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Your solution has fixed my error. I did also make a few changes and remove 'Dis_Msg' as it was redundant. Kind Regards Ben

Comment: if it did, kindly choose it as accepted answer.thanks and happy coding =)

Answer (score 2):

In your first set of errors, you declared the function as using a VARCHAR2 variable, but didn't state a length in brackets after it. State a length

In your second set of errors you called the function `add_location_viasqldev` which takes 0 arguments, but you provided 3. Provide another argument or call a different function

Also, you can make your if/else a bit neater by doing:

```
IF test
ELSIF test
ELSIF test
ELSE
END IF;
```

Comment: When you declare a procedure, the VARCHAR2 arguments don't need length values. `PLS-00215` error is due to declaration of variables `Dis_Msg` and `ploccode` in procedure `ADD_LOCATION_VIASQLDEV`

Comment: Varchar2 parameters for pl/sql function/procedure should not have length specified. The answer is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, you definitely helped me identify that i was supplying only 3 values with no containers to catch them. Regards Ben

Comment: @nitish true, I was having a brain delay and picked on the wrong occurrence of varchar2 thanks

Comment: @wolfrevokcats amended